# Github Action output not saving

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm attempting to save the result of a GitHub Actions job to be used by another job, like this:

```bash
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: |
          ./my-command
          [ $? == 0 ] && result="Success" || result="Failure"
          echo "result=$result" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}
```

The issue I'm having is this will never show "Failure" as the output, only ever "Success". If `./my-command` has a non-zero exit code, it will show nothing.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`run` steps by default run with `bash --noprofile --norc -eo pipefail {0}` under the hood (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell)); this includes the "error on exit" option, which makes the run step abort if `./my-command` isn't successful. To avoid that, you can use a construct like

```bash
if ./my-command; then
    result="Success"
else
    result="Failure"
fi
  
echo "result=$result" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

in the `run` step. A non-zero exit status in a conditional does *not* trigger error-on-exit behaviour of the `-e` option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @benjamin-w wrote, you also have a variable named incorrectly in your YAML

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      # The variable name of the output here needs to match what you write to $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.result }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: |
          ./my-command
          [ $? == 0 ] && result="Success" || result="Failure"
          echo "result=$result" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}
```

Notice that I changed `steps.step1.outputs.test` to `steps.step1.outputs.result`. You used the name `result` when you wrote the value out to `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`.